# Trouble Installing ImageMagick for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick, imagemagick-convert

I just downloaded ImageMagick but am not sure if it's working. I typed in 'which convert' into my terminal and nothing happened. I also tried typing in 'convert logo: logo.gif' then 'identify logo.gif' and lastly 'display logo.gif' and nothing seemed to happen (these three commands were specified on Windows).

Then I tried following this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEWAVlNCKhg

However, it still didn't work and on the last step of the video. I got the following error: ERROR: While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption) invalid option: ----with-opt-include=C:/ImageMagick/SourceCode

Can anyone advise on how to correctly install imagemagick on windows or what these errors mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That video has a bunch of unnecessary stuff if all you want to do is get ImageMagick working as a standalone product on Windows. All you need to do is:

1. Download latest Windows binary from [imagemagick.org](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows). Right now, that file is located [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.6-8-Q16-x86-dll.exe).
2. Run the installer (leave all default values the way they are)
3. Open a command prompt (Start --> Run --> cmd.exe)
4. Navigate to the ImageMagick folder in the command prompt window. For the default install path, this is done as follows :
5. Change to the root directory of the C: drive (type cd\ followed by the enter key)
6. Change to the ImageMagick folder (type cd "Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16" followed by the enter key)
7. Test that it's working with the convert command: convert images\logo.jpg logo.gif
8. Look at the directory listing and check the for a logo.gif file with the current time/datestamp (dir logo.gif, followed by enter key).

**Note:** when you run the convert command, there will not be any output to the command prompt unless you turn on the verbose flag e.g. (convert -verbose images\logo.jpg logo.gif)

Comment: Hmm....nothing seems to have happened when I did this. There were no images being displayed and the command prompt acted as though nothing happened

Comment: ImageMagick Display did not come up or anything else. I am running from Powershell GitShell fwiw.

Comment: Well - ImageMagick Display did not come up but I think in the directory logo is already a gif file (and they recommend trying this on the wizard file too but that is already a jpg as well). What do you think it means if ImageMagick Display doesn't open. 'which convert' is not a recognized command either. Here is the error which came up after typing 'which convert': pastie.org/private/cekiinecnthpnpdb9w3eja

Comment: When you execute the convert command, there will be no visible output from ImageMagick to the command prompt unless you use the -verbose flag when running the command e.g. (convert -verbose images\logo.jpg logo.gif). The only way you know it works is that there is now a logo.gif file that wasn't there before. You can do a few things to verify that the convert command worked: 1) type dir logo.gif and check the timedate stamp 2) delete the logo.gif in your directory and recreate it 3) type imdisplay <enter>, then open the logo.gif file

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in my installation that there was not a 'display.exe', but there was an 'imdisplay.exe".  I tried using imdisplay in a folder that had images, and it did not how a window.  I double clicked imdisplay.exe in the installation folder, and windows came up, including all of the ones I tried to open on the command line.  When I closed all of those windows and tried the command line again, it worked.

I am not sure where you are getting 'which convert' (I did not watch the video).  I can see all of the exe files that are available in the installation folder.  convert.exe is one of them, so in a regular cmd window (I do not know anything about Powershell GitShell), you can just type:
convert logo.png logo.jpg

or something like that.